# Testing a Stored Procedure in Laravel, MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, laravel, azure, stored-procedures

I want to call a stored procedure in my Laravel project. I am using a MSSQL Azure DB. For example this one:[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOorZ.png)

```
DECLARE @return_value int, @OutputReference xml
EXEC @return_value = [sp_GetAllShopInfo] @OutputReference = @OutputReference OUTPUT
SELECT @OutputReference as N'@OutputReference' SELECT 'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

I want to return a data table, a return value (int) and an outputreference (xml).

DB::select() and inserting the query does not work for me. I won't get the return value and outputreference back.

I tried this [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYLAF.png)

Unfortunately I get an error saying:

> The $OutputReference and $ReturnValue is undefined.

```
public function testSP()
    {
        try {
            // Roep de stored procedure aan om de resultaten op te halen
            $results = DB::select('
            DECLARE @return_value int;
            DECLARE @OutputReference xml;
    
            EXEC @return_value = [sp_GetAllShopInfo]
                @OutputReference = @OutputReference OUTPUT;

            SELECT @OutputReference as OutputReference, @return_value as ReturnValue;
        ');

            if (!empty($results)) {
                // Haal de XML-response en returnwaarde op
                $xmlResponse = $results[0]->OutputReference;
                $returnValue = $results[0]->ReturnValue;

                // Doe iets met de XML-response en returnwaarde
                return response()->json([
                    'message' => 'Stored procedure uitgevoerd',
                    'xmlResponse' => $xmlResponse,
                    'returnValue' => $returnValue,
                ]);
            } else {
                // Geen resultaten ontvangen van de stored procedure
                return response()->json(['error' => 'Geen resultaten ontvangen']);
            }
        } catch (QueryException $e) {
            // Als een databasefout optreedt, genereer een aangepaste foutmelding
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Databasefout']);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please could you share your code as text not images so it can be easy to help you ?

Comment: Ofcourse! I have changed my post

Comment: perhaps add `set nocount ON;` in the beginning of your script, sometimes it messes up the results

Comment: Hints: 1) Place `SET NOCOUNT ON` as first line in yor complex T-SQL script 2) Create and use `PDO` object 3) Fetch all results from your statements to make all output parameters available. This is a similar [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76588311/in-php-while-calling-a-parametrized-sql-server-stored-procedures-how-to-get-da/76588419#76588419).

Comment: Thankyou but I can't return the xml response [{"OutputReference":null,"0":null,"ReturnValue":0,"1":0}]]}

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the way you're using `DB::select`. Your SQL looks like this.

```
DECLARE ...;
EXEC ...;
SELECT ...;
```

`DECLARE`, `EXEC` and `SELECT` are 3 different statements. `DB::select` is used to return the values from a `SELECT` statement.

For statements that do not return values (or statements for which you don't really care about returned values), you need to use `DB::statement` instead.

```php
DB::statement("DECLARE ...");
DB::statement("EXEC ...");
$result = DB::select("SELECT ...");
```

```php
DB::statement("DECLARE @return_value int, @OutputReference xml");
DB::statement("EXEC @return_value = [sp_GetAllShopInfo] @OutputReference = @OutputReference OUTPUT");
$result = DB::select("SELECT @OutputReference as OutputReference, @return_value as ReturnValue");
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I changed this in my code but still get this error```"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 20018 Must declare the scalar variable \"@return_value\". [20018] (severity 15) [EXEC @return_value = [sp_GetAllShopInfo] @OutputReference = @OutputReference OUTPUT] (Connection: sqlsrv, SQL: EXEC @return_value = [sp_GetAllShopInfo] @OutputReference = @OutputReference OUTPUT)"```

Comment: I'm not familiar with mssql. What if you put the DECLARE and EXEC inside a single DB::statement ?